# error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor in workato

Tags: database, oracle, workato

OPA error: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (CONNECTION_ID=DKykpGMwR8iPY0r3bveiZg==)

when i am trying to connect  oracle 19c with workato in onprem setup it showing above error the listner is working fine in sqlplus and oracle sql developer but not able to connect to workato in onprem setup[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKMAg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDWcO.png)

i tried checking listner status and also i restrated listner

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your working connection settings in SQL Developer, but based on [the Workato documentation](https://docs.workato.com/connectors/oracle/introduction.html#step-2-define-the-connection-settings-in-workato), it looks like you should change these fields:

**Database host**: localhost (don't put the port or sid/service name here)

**Database name**: orcl (this is the Oracle sid or service name)